# Why is the first row of elements acting different within flexbox?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me by explaining why the top row has more bottom margin inside the flexbox despite them all having the same css, as well as how to fix it so they all behave the same?

I posted this previously but didnt include the html output.

here is what the grid looks like. The to row of elements should act the same as the second row and i don't understand why they are higher than the others. Please help.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
.grid-whole-container {
  display: inline;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  align-content: flex-start
}

.grid-standard-post-container {
  width: 32%;
  flex: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 19px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 19px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 19px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  float: left;
}

.grid-standard-post-container:hover {}

.grid-standard-title-container {
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.grid-standard-title {
  font-family: coolvetica;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  text-shadow: 2.5px 3px black;
  font-size: 27px;
  position: relative;
  top: 80px;
}

.grid-standard-date-container {
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.grid-standard-date {
  letter-spacing: 6px;
  color: black;
  font-family: coolvetica;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 60px;
}

.grid-button button {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
  margin-right: 25%;
  position: relative;
  top: 90px;
  background: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  outline: none;
  font-family: coolvetica;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 7px;
}

.grid-load-more {
  margin-top: 100px;
}


/* INDEX GRID LAYOUT - QUOTE           ========================================================================        ============================= */

.grid-quote-post-container {
  width: 32%;
  flex: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 10px 10px 19px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 10px 10px 19px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 19px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  float: left;
  background-color: #aecfd7;
}

.grid-quote-icon-container {
  color: white;
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: -70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
  <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
    <div class="grid-post-loop-container exhale-posts-container">
      <div class="grid-whole-container">
        <div class="page-limit" data-page="/">
          <article id="grid-post-147 " class="post-147 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorised">
            <header class="grid-entry-header">
              <div class="grid-standard-post-container" style="background: url(http://localhost:8888/MySite/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/marble.jpeg); background-size: cover; ">
                <div class="grid-standard-title-container">
                  <h2 class="grid-standard-title">text post</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-standard-date-container">
                  <h5 class="grid-standard-date">08/02/19</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-button">
                  <a href="http://localhost:8888/MySite/2019/02/08/text-post/" class="btn"><button>Read More</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </header>
          </article>

          <article id="grid-post-132 " class="post-132 post type-post status-publish format-quote hentry category-uncategorised post_format-post-format-quote">
            <div class="grid-quote-entry-header">
              <div class="grid-quote-post-container">
                <div class="grid-quote-icon-container">
                  <i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-standard-title-container">
                  <h2 class="grid-standard-title">quote post 1</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-standard-date-container">
                  <h5 class="grid-standard-date">08/02/19</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-button">
                  <a href="http://localhost:8888/MySite/2019/02/08/sdfghjkl/" class="btn"><button>Read More</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>

          <article id="grid-post-130 " class="post-130 post type-post status-publish format-video hentry category-uncategorised post_format-post-format-video">
            <div class="grid-quote-entry-header">
              <div class=" grid-quote-post-container">
                <div class="grid-quote-icon-container">
                  <i class="fas fa-video"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-standard-title-container">
                  <h2 class="grid-standard-title">video post 1</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-standard-date-container">
                  <h5 class="grid-standard-date">08/02/19</h5>
                </div>
                <div class=" grid-button" id="video-button">
                  <a href="http://localhost:8888/MySite/2019/02/08/new-vid/" class="btn"><button>Read More</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>

          <article id="grid-post-124 " class="post-124 post type-post status-publish format-image has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorised post_format-post-format-image">
            <header class="grid-entry-header">
              <div class="grid-standard-post-container" style="background: url(http://localhost:8888/MySite/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/Screen-Shot-2018-12-28-at-20.26.42.png); background-size: cover; ">
                <div class="grid-standard-title-container">
                  <h2 class="grid-standard-title">Example text post 1</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-standard-date-container">
                  <h5 class="grid-standard-date">07/02/19</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-button">
                  <a href="http://localhost:8888/MySite/2019/02/07/moo-moos-is-shit/" class="btn"><button>Read More</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </header>
          </article>

          <article id="grid-post-122 " class="post-122 post type-post status-publish format-image has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorised post_format-post-format-image">
            <header class="grid-entry-header">
              <div class="grid-standard-post-container" style="background: url(http://localhost:8888/MySite/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/snow.png); background-size: cover; ">
                <div class="grid-standard-title-container">
                  <h2 class="grid-standard-title">Image post 1</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-standard-date-container">
                  <h5 class="grid-standard-date">07/02/19</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-button">
                  <a href="http://localhost:8888/MySite/2019/02/07/snow-day/" class="btn"><button>Read More</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </header>
          </article>

          <article id="grid-post-120 " class="post-120 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-uncategorised">
            <header class="grid-entry-header">
              <div class="grid-standard-post-container" style="background: url(http://localhost:8888/MySite/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/pic-2.png); background-size: cover; ">
                <div class="grid-standard-title-container">
                  <h2 class="grid-standard-title">text post 2</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-standard-date-container">
                  <h5 class="grid-standard-date">06/02/19</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-button">
                  <a href="http://localhost:8888/MySite/2019/02/06/a-weekend-in-prague/" class="btn"><button>Read More</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </header>
          </article>

          <article id="grid-post-107 " class="post-107 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-lifestyle category-travel">
            <header class="grid-entry-header">
              <div class="grid-standard-post-container" style="background: url(http://localhost:8888/MySite/wp-content/uploads/2019/02/Screen-Shot-2017-01-23-at-22.57.39.png); background-size: cover; ">
                <div class="grid-standard-title-container">
                  <h2 class="grid-standard-title">text post 3</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-standard-date-container">
                  <h5 class="grid-standard-date">06/02/19</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-button">
                  <a href="http://localhost:8888/MySite/2019/02/06/how-to-get-a-peng-sunset-pic/" class="btn"><button>Read More</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </header>
          </article>

          <article id="grid-post-98 " class="post-98 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-europe category-lifestyle category-travel tag-new-york tag-nyc">
            <header class="grid-entry-header">
              <div class="grid-standard-post-container" style="background: url(http://localhost:8888/MySite/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/26854339_2115334451827147_1753951410_o.jpg); background-size: cover; ">
                <div class="grid-standard-title-container">
                  <h2 class="grid-standard-title">text post 4</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-standard-date-container">
                  <h5 class="grid-standard-date">28/01/19</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-button">
                  <a href="http://localhost:8888/MySite/2019/01/28/a-stress-free-three-days-in-nyc/" class="btn"><button>Read More</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </header>
          </article>

          <article id="grid-post-74 " class="post-74 post type-post status-publish format-quote hentry category-travel tag-famous-quotes post_format-post-format-quote">
            <div class="grid-quote-entry-header">
              <div class="grid-quote-post-container">
                <div class="grid-quote-icon-container">
                  <i class="fas fa-quote-left"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-standard-title-container">
                  <h2 class="grid-standard-title">quote post 2</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-standard-date-container">
                  <h5 class="grid-standard-date">25/01/19</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="grid-button">
                  <a href="http://localhost:8888/MySite/2019/01/25/andre-gide/" class="btn"><button>Read More</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Comment: Would be nice for us if you could properly format your code :)

Comment: Really sorry im fairly new to stack overflow and it took me a while for actually get it to come up as code after I had to add 8 spaces in front. This is the code that I took directly from my source code on the page. I used php to create this page. It may have messed up a bit after trying to indent it properly to get it to come up as code when creating this question :)

Comment: can someone please help. its working on the snippet and not the actual page. i am desperate please help

Comment: It's difficult to help you if the code snippet does not reproduce the problem... Try adding other images of different widths and heights to your snippet to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Are you familiar with browser developer tools? They should help identify where the errant styles are coming from.

Comment: omg opened dev tools and found what it was. I had styled 'article' elsewhere in CSS. Thank you so much for suggesting that. I almost cried.